# WKWebView content terminates in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, avplayer, wkwebview

Our application has a `WKWebView` playing an embedded video (an iFrame). The desired effect is to have the audio continue playing when the app goes into the background.

We are seeing the [`-webViewWebContentProcessDidTerminate:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKNavigationDelegate_Ref/) method being called called ~10 seconds after the app goes into the background.

When this occurs we are able to reload the web view and continue playback from the previous point, but this leaves a 2-4 second gap in the playback due to buffering- not a good experience for our users.

Any ideas how to get `WKWebView` to continue video playback in the background. I have read [Apple's guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1668/_index.html) on this, but we do not have access to WKWebView's underlying AVPlayer.

Comment: can you not play the audio directly using a native AVPlayer?

Comment: @Scriptable I should've clarified. We are playing the media using an iFrame so we don't have access to the direct file URL.

Comment: Any news on this?

Comment: @Daniel Unfortunately not. We later removed this feature from our application.